# NSManagedObject know to clear cache when it has been updated via a background thread?

Tags: ios, caching, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an NSManagedObject which builds a cached structure from one of its properties. When this object gets updated via a background thread with seperate context the actual property values themselves all propagate down but the object needs some notification that this has happened it can drop its cache.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Possibly dependent keys and KVO https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html